# Depictions of 19th c Vienna for a chronicle

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem, historical-settings

I would like to create a *Vampire: the Requiem* chronicle set in 19th century Vienna. Are there any good films or books depicting Vienna in this period that I could use to create appropriate scenery and atmosphere?

Comment: Questions like these have attracted some controversy lately. Can you give us an idea what parts of VtR you're hoping to emphasize in the setting, or another more concrete link to the game?

Comment: @Seven: Isn't _XIX_ equal to 19 in roman numerals, so it's the 19th century?

Comment: @yhw42 Yeah my bad. I saw XIX and read XIV. That just supports the need to convert it into Arabic numerals. ;)

Comment: What I would like to emphasize? How people dressed. How streets looked like. How aristocratic balls were hosted. Everything that will allow me to show my players, that they aren't playing in generic 21st century.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some 1870-1900 travel guides with bits about Vienna in the period:

[The illustrated English guide through Vienna and its environs (1873)](http://books.google.com/books?id=MTYuAAAAYAAJ&dq=vienna+tourist&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

[A handy illustrated guide to Vienna (1906)](http://books.google.com/books?id=G6ZDAAAAYAAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

[A Satchel guide for the vacation tourist in Europe (1873)](http://books.google.com/books?id=1RwoAAAAYAAJ&dq=vienna+tourist&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

[Notes from the Journal of a Tourist: Italy, Spain, central and northern Europe (1890)](http://books.google.com/books?id=AnELAAAAYAAJ&dq=vienna+tourist&source=gbs_navlinks_s), fist hand account of the Vienna Exposition

A couple of colorful older narratives:

Coke's [Vienna in 1848](http://books.google.com/books?id=dplDAAAAYAAJ&dq=vienna&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (well illustrated)

[Travels from Vienna through lower Hungary:with some remarks on the state of Vienna during the congress, in the year 1814](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ZTVAAAAMAAJ&dq=vienna&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

[Vienna and the Austrians: With some account of a journey through Swabia, Bavaria, the Tyrol, and the Salzbourg, Volume 1 (1838)](http://books.google.com/books?id=3bYAAAAAcAAJ&dq=vienna&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

Neil Burger's not-very-good film [The Illusionist](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0443543/) is set in fin-de-siecle Vienna. Milos Foreman's [Amadeus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086879/) is also Vienna-rific.

Comment: That is a great answer, thanks a lot! Do you know about any books/films about the second half of 19th century? I am starting my campaign in 1867 (the day, when union between Austria and Hungary is created) and princess of Vienna is hosting a ball. That's why I would love to see, how Vienna looked in years 1870-1900.